# Parsing HTML code to find a link

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to get a link that is buried in an html code (does not show up on the website). I've tried parsing the page with BeautifulSoup, but it only gets the links on the webpage. Is there a way to parse html code to find the link?

Comment: Absolutely - but please do post some code showing the link you'd to extract and what you've attempted so far. It's easier for people to help that way...

Comment: It is very unclear without showing us the HTML code you are parsing and the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything that is in the sourcecode of a html page, in your case it probably looks like http://someurl>. Php can do the job for you, if you give me more details about the link and in what website you are trying to find the link and what you want to do with it, I might look into some of my own code made for extracting url's (links) from any given website.

I found a nice example code for you (does more than extracting url's). This will hopefully help you on your way: http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_23.php